# URL contains # resulting in error

Tags: errors, urls

```
\begin{frame}{Triphala Churn}
     \begin{enumerate}
     \item  Three fruits – Amalaki [Indian Gooseberry – Emblica officinalis], Haritaki [Myrobalan – Terminalia chebula], and Vibhatika [Belleric Myrobalan – Terminalia belerica]
    \item Laxative 
    \item result in allergic reaction including anaphylaxis 
     \end{enumerate}
     Ref: http://www.stylecraze.com/articles/harmful-side-effects-of-triphala-churna/#gref
    \end{frame}
```

I am getting error possibly because of #gref. What is the solution. I tried $..$ to include it as math symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Package `url` provides `\url`, which takes care of special characters. Also
option `fragile`is probably needed for the frame:

```
\usepackage{url}% (shold be already loaded by `hyperref`, which is loaded by `beamer`)

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  ...
  \url{http://www.example.org/index.html#gref}
\end{frame}
```